# What's the most efficient way to capture data from an API call and dump it into a dataset (or datatable)?

Tags: xml, asp.net-web-api

I have an API which returns data from a database table. This data comes back as an XML.

What would be the most efficient way to capture the XML that is returned by the API and dump that data into a dataset (or datatable).

Basically what I need to do is just capture the data the API returns (which is an XML) and then "transform" it to look like a database table (which ill be displaying on a grid in a web application).

I was thinking about using LINQ to XML but i dont think that's an efficient way to transform that XML into a database table.

Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: what programming language or toolkit are you using to generate the web application? if you just want an HTML table, you don't need a "database table"...

Comment: im using visual studio 2012. the API was built using ASP .NET MVC Web API with Entity Framework 5. the other application, the one which will consume the API will be done using Web Forms, C#.

Comment: well, then use [XmlTextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.xmltextreader(v=vs.80).aspx) or some other lib to parse the XML and then output the HTML table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
public static DataTable GetDataTableFromAPI(string url)
        {
            using (var webclient = new WebClient())
            {
                string jDoc = webclient.DownloadString(url);

                var table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jDoc);

                return table;
            }
        }
```